# Keyboard shortcut for going to previous/next files in Finder/QuickLook?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

Let's say that I'm viewing files as icons in Finder. I want to be able to QuickLook through all the files in a directory, but using the left and right arrows in QuickLook will only let me navigate a "row" of files. I could switch to list view and then use the up and down arrows; but is there another approach I could use within icon view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that: Use <kbd>⇥</kbd> (Tab)!

To go backwards, use <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⇥</kbd> (Shift-Tab).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Amazing, the Mac secrets that remain unbeknownst to me...